# SOLR 1.3.0 download

Tags: solr, version

I am supposed to use SOLR 1.3.0 for pre-existing business reasons. The least version of SOLR available for download is 1.4.1.

Can somebody help me with a link to download 1.3.0. Almost all the pages pointed out by google either return a 404 or show the list of latest releases.

Comment: Probably its time to upgrade .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can't upgrade then maybe check http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/solr/branches/branch-1.3 and build from source.

Comment: I'd recommend http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/solr/tags/release-1.3.0/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its too late, but [this](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/1.3.0/) may help.

(This was posted on the Apache Solr mailing list by Chris Hostetter)